# Разные ссылки для скачивания

Tags: защита, контент

Пытаюсь скачать с ютуба с помощью [вот этого](https://ru.savefrom.net/) ресурса. Почему-то некоторые видео, например, [это](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mjs7O2K0nxI&t=268s), скачать не получается. Это потому что они как-то защищены от скачивания ?

Comment: У меня пишет "видео не доступно", возможно это видео или в нестандартном формате, или доступно только для зарегистрированых пользователей.

Comment: Я зарегистрирован .

Comment: Так на savefrom.ne я и не вижу , где регистрироваться.

Comment: Таки да: пожалуйста , смотри.

Comment: У меня просмотр данного видео не доступен. Если у кого-то ещё недоступен - можете добавлять "голос". Почему видео может бы недоступно - обьяснить не могу. Тупо надпись "Видео недоступно"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не через это ресурс - можно скачать напрямую, через плагин к браузеру (если видео недоступно, то нужно зайти через прокси):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

UPD по комменту:

*Плагины разные есть для разных браузеров -  этот для `firefox`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

*По переводчику:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Извините за недалёкость, а плагин-то какой ?

Comment: Добавил в ответ

Comment: А не подскажете ,какие плагины нужны для ие или Хрома ? А то лишнюю программу неохото тащить на ноутбук из-за такой ерунды.

Comment: Ну, FireFox лишним не будет - в отличие от многих браузеров, он очень скромно себя ведет и не нарушает правильного течения... А с chrom могут быть заморочки - часто такое выходит: Download from YouTube is disabled due to Chrome Web Store policy.

Comment: Всё, большое спасибо , установил и браузер , и плагин, качает , как зверь Считай, пока я этот коммент писал, то видео и скачалось.

Comment: А вы случайно не знаете , есть ли плагин у firefox для перевода просматриваемых страниц на другие языки? Я только из-за этого предпочитаю Хром перед ие.

Comment: Пожалуйста) - По переводчику добавил в коммент - очень удобный. - ImTranslator: выполняет мгновенный перевод текста, слов и веб-страниц для более 90 языков, используя 3 провайдера перевода. Подробности в настройках после установки - на русском, если браузер на русском будет.